# How to show a div as a loading page after clicking the submit button?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a login form where I get the username and password.

Now I need to show a loading page after the user clicks the submit button.

I have a div that contains "your process is loading". This div needs to load using Ajax call after the button is pressed.

I tried with the below code but it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#loading").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
            $(this).show();
        }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
            $(this).hide();
        }).bind("ajaxError", function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: The jsfiddle link that you supplied does exactly what you ask... http://jsfiddle.net/jveldboom/c73MQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

Hide it on your ajax success callback. Something like this:

```
$(".your-loading-div").show();
$.ajax({
    url: 'mypage.html',
    success: function(){
        $(".your-loading-div").hide();
    },
    error: function(){
        $(".your-loading-div").hide();
        alert('failure');
    }
});
```